# Getting "Invalid format" error during server side auth in Oauth.io

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, oauth, oauth.io

I have a javascript client and a laravel backend and I am using Oauth.IO for social authentication. I followed the steps specified here: http://docs.oauth.io/#authorizing-the-user-with-both-front-end-and-back-end-sdks

I successfully got state token by calling `generateStateToken()` method, but when I send that to `$this->oauth->auth()` method I get **Invalid Format** error. Can you please tell me what this error means and what I am doing wrong.

**Client Side**

```
var selectedAuth = 'facebook';
$.post('http://localhost/auth/v1/social', {provider: selectedAuth, get_state_token: 1}, function(data){
    OAuth.popup(selectedAuth)
    .done(function(result) {
        console.log(result);
        $.post('http://localhost/auth/v1/social', {provider: selectedAuth, code: data.token, access_token: result.access_token}, function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }, 'json');
    })
    .fail(function (err) {
        //handle error with err
    });
}, 'json');
```

**Server Side**

```
// code to get the state token in a different method
$token = $this->oauth->generateStateToken();
return response()->json(['status' => 'success', 'token' => $token]);
```

-- snip --

```
// code to get access token from state token in another method
$provider = 'facebook';
$request_object = $this->oauth->auth($provider, array(
    'code' => $code
));
$credentials = $request_object->getCredentials();
```

I have verified that `$code` does have the exact state token that I have received on the 1st step.
The value of `$credentials` is as follows:

`{"status":"error","data":{"code":"Invalid format"},"refreshed":false}`

Please help me out here. This error occurs for both for facebook and twitter as well. Let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 1):

I am really sorry for posting this question. I had missed a step in the documentation. I am leaving this question here as a reference for others in case anyone else faces the same issue.

The error was in my javascript code. While calling `Oauth.popup()`, I needed to pass the state token and get a code which was then supposed to be passed to the server. I was sending the state token to the server directly instead of the code.

The correct code will be this :

```
var selectedAuth = 'facebook';
$.post('http://localhost/auth/v1/social', {provider: selectedAuth, get_state_token: 1}, function(data){
    OAuth.popup(selectedAuth, {
        state: data.token
    })
    .done(function(result) {
        console.log(result);
        $.post('http://localhost/auth/v1/social', {provider: selectedAuth, code: result.code, access_token: result.access_token}, function(data){
             console.log(data);
        }, 'json');
    })
    .fail(function (err) {
        //handle error with err
    });
 }, 'json');
```